# How to override post method of generics.ListCreateAPIView?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, backend

guys.
I'm writing backend for application that allow voting for best pizza.

I have Pizza model (id, name, price),
built-in User model,
Vote model(id, author [models.ForeignKey], pizza[models.ForeignKey]).

In my project I implement view

```
class VoteList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer
```

And now I want to implement
check if authenticated user posts vote with his id.
If it is True, I want to save it into the datebase,
else I don't want to save it and return HTTP with error

```
if request.user.pk == self.serializer_class.Meta.model.author:
```

So could you, please, help me to implement this functionality

Answer (score 0):

The django rest framework tutorial cover this part (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/). I recommand you follow along the tutorial from the beginning (it's very short), it will make more sense.